# How ASP.NET MVC _layout variables work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I create a new ASP.NET 4.5 web application MVC in Visual Studio, it starts with a introduction template.

The relavant parts are:

**Views/Home/About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
...
```

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
...
    @RenderBody()
...
```

**Views/_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If I understand right, and assuming the About page is opened in the browser:

- The **_ViewStart.cshtml** is called first, and it says there is a layout **_Layout.cshtml** to be called.
- It renders the **_Layout.cshtml**, until the call **@RenderBody()** is reached, on that point he will render the **About.cshtml**. When that ends, he will render the rest of the **_Layout.cshtml**.

But here is my doubt, if the **_Layout.cshtml** starts first, how does it print on the `<title>` the variable `@ViewBag.Title`, which is assigned only in **About.cshtml**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hit a URL an **Action** is called on a **controller**. The view is a result of this, so you don't call views directly (my guess is your coming from a webforms background where you call an aspx page, MVC uses a different model that doesn't rely on physical files). The action then specifies which view to render (and passes it the model). This view then specifies a layout to use when rendering the view.

So the control mechanism is inverted compared to what your used to.

URL (via routing) specifies a controller and an action -> the action says render me using this view -> the view then says render me using this layout. So the hierachy is:

- Controller
- Action
- View
- Layout

So to answer your specific questions:

> But here is my doubt, if the _Layout.cshtml starts first, how does it
>   print on the `<title>` the variable `@ViewBag.Title`, which is assigned
>   only in About.cshtml?

The layout isn't called first, the view specifies a layout that should be used to render itself.

Comment: It makes more sense now. I've tried to assign the variable on the layout instead, and it wouldn't appear on the View, meaning the order really is from View to Layout. And I've tried to remove the @RenderBody() and it gave an error, meaning that rendering depends on that. So first the program logic goes from the Controller to the Layout. And only then it starts rendering the layout, which will include the View.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't. The View is rendered before the layout.